# TCP/IP using Socket Test 3.0 software

Tags: sockets, tcp

I have 'Socket test v-3.0' software installed on two different PCs.
Using it can create a TCP server on 1st PC and a TCP client on 2nd PC.

When I connect both the PCs on LAN I can establish a connection & can communicate between the Server & Client.

But, When I connect both the PCs to individual Internet connections (Using dongles having different ISPs), I couldn't establish the connection between the Server & Client.

How can I do that?
Please help me out..

Comment: Your server PC probably does not have a routable IP address and it is behind a NAT device so client can not connect. Can you ping your from client to server when they are connected to different ISPs?

Comment: Thanks Sir for the fast reply..   What does a routable IP mean?? & How to ping?? how to get my server IP addrees?

Comment: Perhaps you could read some IP tutorial. The commands `ifconfig` on unix based systems and `ipconfig` on MS systems shows your IP address. If your IP address starts with `10.` or `192.168.` or `172.16. - 172.32.` then your IP address is private and nobody from public internet can directly connect to it. You can ping by command name `ping`.

Comment: Thanks sir... I checked it using ipconfig command.. My IP starts with 192.168.... How can it be public??

Answer (score 1):

The private address `192.168.x.x` is address that can be used for direct connection only in your private network. If you want to connect to your machine from public internet you have two options:

- Get a public IP address
- Configure a port forwarding

Public IP address could be get from your internet provider but it is usually requires some extra payment dependent on your service provider policy.

Port forwarding can be configured at the device at the border between your private network and internet. The device does the NAT (network address translation) between your private network and intenet. Use google if you are not sure about NAT.

Such a device can be your own device like an ADSL modem or a set top box. But such a device could be in the internet provider network. If you own the device then you can configure the port forwarding yourself. Modems usually have a web interface where you can easily configure port forwarding. See the documentation to your modem or whatever you have.

If the NAT device is in internet provider network then you have to ask it to configure port forwarding for you. Before you ask please read something about port forwarding so you are sure what you want to configure.